# IDempiere ERP, How can i add ubuntu user interface while running on virtual machine?

Tags: idempiere

Whenever i run tasksel, there is a message will appear that want me to install predefined collection of software, which software i will install?

I expect a step by step tutorial on how to set up Ubutu ui on virtual machine

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.